# return value to vba from xlwings

Tags: python, vba, excel, xlwings

Let's use the example on [xlwings documentation](http://docs.xlwings.org/vba.html).

Given the following python code:

```
import numpy as np
from xlwings import Workbook, Range

def rand_numbers():
    """ produces std. normally distributed random numbers with shape (n,n)"""
    wb = Workbook.caller()  # Creates a reference to the calling Excel file
    n = int(Range('Sheet1', 'B1').value)  # Write desired dimensions into Cell B1
    rand_num = np.random.randn(n, n)
    Range('Sheet1', 'C3').value = rand_num
```

This is the original example.

Let's say we modify it slightly to be:

```
import numpy as np
from xlwings import Workbook, Range

def rand_numbers():
    """ produces std. normally distributed random numbers with shape (n,n)"""
    wb = Workbook.caller()  # Creates a reference to the calling Excel file
    n = int(Range('Sheet1', 'B1').value)  # Write desired dimensions into Cell B1
    rand_num = np.random.randn(n, n)
    return rand_num #modified line
```

And we call it from VBA using the following call:

```
Sub MyMacro()
    dim z 'new line'
    z = RunPython ("import mymodule; mymodule.rand_numbers()")
End Sub
```

We get `z` as an empty value.

Is there any way to return a value to vba directly without writing to a text file, or putting the value first in the excel document?

Thank you for any pointers.

Comment: I don't work with python but see if [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639887/Calling-Python-code-from-Excel-with-ExcelPython) is what you want?

Comment: Thank you but the question is xlwings specific. I appreciate the input but unfortunately it is not the goal of my question (again, this is my fault not yours - the scope just needs to speak to xlwings due to other infrastructure).

Answer (score 2):

***RunPython does not allow you to return values*** as per xlwings documentation. 
To overcome these issue, use UDFs, see VBA: User Defined Functions (UDFs) - however, this is currently limited to Windows only.

https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/udfs.html#udfs